# Function composition and Bell polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

Suppose that we have the Taylor expansions :
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n!}x^{n}$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_{n}}{n!}x^{n}$$
Then we have the [standard result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Fa.C3.A0_di_Bruno.27s_formula) :
$$g(f(x))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k}B_{n,k}(a_{1},...,a_{n-k+1})\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Where $B_{n,k}(\cdot)$ are the [partial Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials). 
Now suppose we have the expansion :
$$h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}(a_{1},...,a_{n})\frac{x^{n}}{(n!)^{2}}\ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Where $B_{n}(\cdot)$ are the complete Bell polynomials. We want to express $h(x)$ in closed form as a composite function. Thus, we use the relation above, and we set:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k}B_{n,k}(a_{1},...,a_{n-k+1})=\frac{B_{n}(a_{1},...,a_{n})}{n!}\ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
How can we solve for $b_{k}$ !?

To be more specific, I'm interested in the relation between the two expansions:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n}\left(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}\right)}{n!}x^{n}\ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
And:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n}\left(a_{1},2!a_{2},...,n!a_{n}\right)}{(n!)^{2}}x^{n}\ \ \ \ \ (5)$$
Using the reasoning above - function composition - or any other method for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the notion

$$a_i=\frac{d^i}{dx^i}f(x)\bigg|_0=f_i,\ \ \ \ \ b_k=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}g(x)\bigg|_0=g_k,\ \ \ \ \ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}h(x)\bigg|_0=h_n.$$

Faà di Bruno's formula is then:

$$g(f(x))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_{k}B_{n,k}(f_1,...,f_{n-k+1})\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}.\tag{1}$$

Equation 2 in connection with equation 1 means $g_k=\frac{1}{n!}$. That means $g_{k_1}\neq g_{k_2}$ for $k_1=k_2$ for different $n$. $g_k$ cannot be a function value of the $k$-th derivative of $g$ therefore. Faà di Bruno's formula is therefore not applicable here.

$ $

$$B_n(f_1,...,f_n)=e^{-f(0)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{f(x)}\bigg|_0$$

$$h_n=\frac{B_n(f_1,...,f_n)}{n!}=e^{-f(0)}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{f(x)}\bigg|_0$$

If e.g. $f(x)=cx$ where $c$ is a constant, $h(x)=I_0(2\sqrt{cx})$, wherein $I$ is the [Modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions).